# ssl error handshake failure alert

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, virtualhost, openssl

I'm getting the error mentioned in the title in Firefox when i try to access my website on my machine. 
This is the error i get :

```
An error occurred during a connection to www.st.um.
SSL peer was unable to negotiate an acceptable set of security parameters.
(Error code: ssl_error_handshake_failure_alert)
```

This is my virtual host configuration :

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin user1@st.um
    ServerName www.st.um
    DocumentRoot /var/www/web
    <Directory /var/www/web>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>    
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /usr/lib/ssl/demoCA/servercert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /usr/lib/ssl/demoCA/serverkey.pem
    SSLCACertificateFile /usr/lib/ssl/demoCA/stcert.pem

    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>

    BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
    nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
    downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

    # MSIE 7 and newer should be able to use keepalive
    BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown

    SSLVerifyClient require
    SSLVerifyDepth 10

</VirtualHost>
```

The certificate "servercert.pem" is certificated using my CA : "stcert.pem" and i can use the certificate "servercert.pem" with the key "serverkey.pem" perfectly to gain access to the s_server as a server and having my CA imported and trusted in the list of authorities of the web browser :

```
openssl s_server -cert servercert.pem -key serverkey.pem -www
```

I also can gain access to my website as a client using a PKCS#12 file generated from a certificate "clientcert.pem" with its key "clientkey.pem".

The only thing that i have in /etc/log/apache2/error.log is :

```
[Sat May 25 02:44:11 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) 
PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.6 with Suhosin-Patch mod_ssl/2.2.22 
OpenSSL/1.0.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

Comment: When i try to access my website in my machine i get the ssl error handshake failure alert in the web browser

Comment: What exactly does the Apache error log say?

Comment: OK, i just updated the question with the complete error description.

Comment: I just edited my virtualhost configuration and deleted "SSLVerifyClient require" and "SSLVerifyDepth 10". And now it is working. I could not answer my own question because it is asking me to wait 8 hours for being a beginner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I edited my virtualhost configuration and deleted :

```
    SSLVerifyClient require
    SSLVerifyDepth 10
```

And now it is working for server-side authentication. The "SSLVerifyClient require" directive override the lines :

```
SSLCertificateFile /usr/lib/ssl/demoCA/servercert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /usr/lib/ssl/demoCA/serverkey.pem
SSLCACertificateFile /usr/lib/ssl/demoCA/stcert.pem
```

And that was the problem. The "SSLVerifyClient require" directive is for client-Side authentication and it makes openSSL to always require a certificate from the client.